# Pocket IE has some maximum width for textboxes?

Tags: windows-mobile, textbox, width, pocket-ie

I have a page running on WinMo 6.1 Pocket IE. 
It seems I cannot make a textbox wider than 219 pixels, is this the case? 
I've tried

```
width="100%"
width="300px"
style="width: 100%;"
style="width: 300px;"
columns="50"
```

but no matter what I do, the textbox will not grow beyond 219 pixels wide, which looks kinda dorky on a 320x screen. Does pIE really limit the width of a textbox???

Comment: By the by, they all work fine and as expected on my desktop browser.

Comment: Even more annoying, it seems to also have a maximum width for textareas, which does not match textboxes! Textareas apparently will not render wider than 183px. Lovely.

Answer (score 1):

also button can't be 100% in size.

Try this forum
http://forums.asp.net/t/1288621.aspx

there is a workaround.

i hope it helps.